# How to you replace tags in file?

Tags: python, templates, haskell, tags

I need to replace some tags in a template file given that the tags are sequenced.
For example:

```
\beqin{document}
text $1
test 3 Dolèren  ipsum $2
$6
```

Lets say that the file is named template.tex and the subtitution script is called like :

```
script /path/template.tex a b c<br/>
```

It should give me :

```
\begin{document}
text a
test 3 Dolèren  ipsum b
```

(see the $6 is ommited because there was no sixth input and the c also because there is no $3)
In short I need a function that has type myfunc :: FilePath -> [String] -> IO ()
The output may be in stdout.

As for the language it may be python or haskell.
 Is there any existing lib that does it?
Am I doomed to use parsec? Or is there any all known way to do it simply?

Please do not tell me to use bash as I am not platform bound.
Also the tag $1 $2 may be something else, like <<1$ <<2$...

Comment: If you want arbitrary tags, you're most likely going to need to write your own parser.  Parsec isn't the only option, as regex replace might make more sense here.

Comment: Doomed to use Parsec isn't such a bad thing, but, yeah, as @bheklilr says, regexes exist in both languages quite nicely.

Comment: `Please do not tell me to use bash as I am not platform bound.` -- Could you elaborate?

Comment: Using parsec seems like an overkill for something so trivial and regex while I understand the syntax reeks of unforseen errors... Just some feeling nothing technical. Also I was hoping that someone had already done it :)

Comment: Check the Jinja2 lib in python

Comment: I could make my template an sh script and gives it the data to echo. But the goals here is to embed the mechanism into an existing project and adding cygwin as dependency for windows is not really wanted.

Comment: Jinja2 is cool ;) You should make it an answer. I would generate xml data store with hxt and produce the actual tex doc with it.

Comment: I made the `inserts` library in Haskell a few days ago. It'd be sufficient for your task, but it uses different syntax. http://hackage.haskell.org/package/inserts

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use my [`inserts`](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/inserts-0.1.0.1/docs/Text-Template-Inserts.html) package. It provides a dead simple template syntax, though it differs from your `$` style syntax.

```
import           Text.Template.Inserts
import qualified Data.ByteString.Char8 as S

doc :: S.ByteString
doc = "\beqin{document}\ntext {{1}}\ntest 3 Dolèren  ipsum {{2}}\n{{6}}\n"

replace :: [S.ByteString] -> S.ByteString -> Maybe S.ByteString
replace vals name = case lookup name dict of
    Nothing          -> Just S.empty
    Just replacement -> Just replacement
  where dict :: [(S.ByteString, S.ByteString)] 
        dict = zip (map (S.pack . show) [1..]) vals

main = case parseTemplate doc of
  Left err -> print err
  Right t  -> case runTemplate replace t of
    Right output -> print output
    Left e       -> error "Impossible!"
```

Answer (score 0):

I suppose renderFormatString function from package [format](http://hackage.haskell.org/package/format-0.1.0.0/docs/Text-Format.html) is exactly what are you looking for.